# How to use Material UI Fade to fade in a component on text field input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a text field input. I want to fade in another, seperate helper component when a user focuses on the input field.

I have wrapped the helper component as such:

```
<Fade in={checked}>
  <DynamicHelperText level={helperLevel} />
</Fade>
```

And added the following to a function that already detects input changes in the text field:

```
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (textInputValue.length) {
      setChecked(true);
    }
  }, [textInputValue.length])
```

(I am also importing 'Fade' from the material library).

However, this does not work. The element is not hidden on load. There are also no compilation or console errors.

Would anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example. Hope it helps you.

```
import {Fade, Paper} from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        height: 180,
    },
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    paper: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    svg: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    },
    polygon: {
        fill: theme.palette.common.white,
        stroke: theme.palette.divider,
        strokeWidth: 1,
    },
}));


function FadeExample() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

    function changeHandler(event) {
        if (event.target.value.length > 0)
            setChecked(true);
        else
            setChecked(false);
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <input onChange={changeHandler}/>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <Fade in={checked}>
                    <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper}>
                        <svg className={classes.svg}>
                            <polygon points="0,100 50,00, 100,100" className={classes.polygon}/>
                        </svg>
                    </Paper>
                </Fade>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FadeExample;
```